# Is a graph with 0 nodes a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

If you have a graph with 1 node and no edges and you then remove this 1 node, is the remaining a graph with 0 nodes or is it not anymore a graph?

Alternative formulation:
Is there something such as a <s>empty</s> null graph?

Comment: Not all favor allowing an empty graph (no vertices). http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NullGraph.html

Comment: And that mathworld article gives the game away. As with any edge-case of a definition you're free to use any definition you like, and typically you'll use whatever definition results in you *not* needing language in your favourite theorem(s) to treat the edge case specially.

Comment: The graph with no vertices should be called the **null graph**. Calling it the **"empty graph"** is confusing, because the term **empty graph** is commonly applied to any graph with **no edges**, i.e., the complement of a complete graph.

Answer (score 14):

This is not quite clear. There is an entire paper dedicated to this question.

'Is the null-graph a pointless concept?' by Frank Harary and Ronald C. Read

Its abstract says (my emphasis):

> The graph with no points and no lines is discussed critically. Arguments for and against its official admittance as a graph are presented. This is accompanied by an extensive survey of the literature. Paradoxical properties of the null-graph are noted. **No conclusion is reached.**

Comment: It definitely exists, it is depicted on the figure 1 of the paper.

Comment: Yes! :-) More seriously, such an object exists; this is clear. The question asked, and discussed in the paper, is should it be called/considered a graph. The question is a bit like if  $0$ is natural number, some think yes some think no while there is agreement that $0$ exists.

Comment: I'd say that any concept you can get a whole paper out of, isn't pointless. But ofc the pun in the title is probably sufficient to publish regardless of content.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is such a thing. A graph with zero nodes is generally referred to as the **null graph**.
The term **empty graph** usually refers to a graph with no edges (but possibly some nodes).

Googling these terms will yield some non-trivial results.

Answer (score 1):

An empty graph might or might not have $0$ nodes. What you are talking about is the empty graph with $0$ nodes. It does exist.